# How do I construct this url rewrite policy in Azure APIM?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

In Azure APIM, looking for a url rewrite policy (I think), that looks for a certain string and constructs the backend url based on that string.

Example1:
Converts this
https://myfrontend.com/locations/usa/remaining-url
to this
https://usa.com/remaining-url

Example1:
Converts this
https://myfrontend.com/locations/canada/remaining-url
to this
https://canada.com/remaining-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your API Management API / Operation.

In my example I designed it this way:

```yaml
'/locations/{locationid}/*':
  get:
    summary: Locations with Id
    operationId: locations-with-id
    parameters:
      - name: locationid
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          enum:
            - usa
            - canada
          type: string
```

There's a matchedparameter `locationid` which will be used in the policy.
The `path` ends with a [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/add-api-manually#add-and-test-a-wildcard-operation) `/*` to support the remaining URL.

For getting the remaining URL, the following [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/upw8nH/1) is used:
`\/locations\/[^\/]*(\/[a-zA-Z0-9-?=#_]*)`

API with operation GET `/locations/{locationid}/*` :

[image]

Operation policy:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="RegexLocation" value="\/locations\/[^\/]*(\/[a-zA-Z0-9-?=#_]*)" />
        <set-variable name="remainingUrl" value="@{
            string pattern = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("RegexLocation");

            var regex = new Regex(pattern);
            var match = regex.Match(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.ToString());

            if (match.Success)
            {  
              return match.Groups[1].Value;;
            }       
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

        }" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.MatchedParameters.GetValueOrDefault("locationid", "") == "usa")">
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://usa.com" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.MatchedParameters.GetValueOrDefault("locationid", "") == "canada")">
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://canada.com" />
            </when>
        </choose>
        <rewrite-uri template="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("remainingUrl"))" copy-unmatched-params="true" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

The `choose` policy is used to specify the backend.
The policy `rewrite-uri` adds the renaming path and query

Output from trace for request:
GET https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net/abc/locations/usa/lorem?ipsum=1

The new backend URL is:
https://usa.com/lorem?ipsum=1

```json
{
  "traceEntries": {
    "inbound": [
      {
        "source": "set-variable",
        "timestamp": "2022-08-13T07:08:45.5496188Z",
        "elapsed": "00:00:00.0003989",
        "data": {
          "message": "Context variable was successfully set.",
          "name": "RegexLocation",
          "value": "\\/locations\\/[^\\/]*(\\/[a-zA-Z0-9-?=#_]*)"
        }
      },
      {
        "source": "set-variable",
        "timestamp": "2022-08-13T07:08:45.5496188Z",
        "elapsed": "00:00:00.0004445",
        "data": {
          "message": "Expression was successfully evaluated.",
          "expression": "\n            string pattern = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>(\"RegexLocation\");\n\n            var regex = new Regex(pattern);\n            var match = regex.Match(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.ToString());\n\n            if (match.Success)\n            {  \n              return match.Groups[1].Value;;\n            }       \n            else\n            {\n                return string.Empty;\n            }\n\n        ",
          "value": "/lorem"
        }
      },
      {
        "source": "set-variable",
        "timestamp": "2022-08-13T07:08:45.5496188Z",
        "elapsed": "00:00:00.0004465",
        "data": {
          "message": "Context variable was successfully set.",
          "name": "remainingUrl",
          "value": "/lorem"
        }
      },
      {
        "source": "choose",
        "timestamp": "2022-08-13T07:08:45.5496188Z",
        "elapsed": "00:00:00.0004581",
        "data": {
          "message": "Expression was successfully evaluated.",
          "expression": "context.Request.MatchedParameters.GetValueOrDefault(\"locationid\", \"\") == \"usa\"",
          "value": true
        }
      },
      {
        "source": "set-backend-service",
        "timestamp": "2022-08-13T07:08:45.5496188Z",
        "elapsed": "00:00:00.0004690",
        "data": {
          "message": "Backend service URL was changed.",
          "oldBackendServiceUrl": "https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net/abc",
          "newBackendServiceUrl": "https://usa.com/",
          "request": { "url": "https://usa.com/locations/usa/lorem?ipsum=1" }
        }
      },
      {
        "source": "rewrite-uri",
        "timestamp": "2022-08-13T07:08:45.5496188Z",
        "elapsed": "00:00:00.0004757",
        "data": {
          "message": "Expression was successfully evaluated.",
          "expression": "context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>(\"remainingUrl\")",
          "value": "/lorem"
        }
      },
      {
        "source": "rewrite-uri",
        "timestamp": "2022-08-13T07:08:45.5496188Z",
        "elapsed": "00:00:00.0005407",
        "data": {
          "message": "Updated request URL per specified rewrite template.",
          "request": { "url": "https://usa.com/lorem?ipsum=1" }
        }
      }
    ],
    "backend": [
      {
        "source": "forward-request",
        "timestamp": "2022-08-13T07:08:45.5496188Z",
        "elapsed": "00:00:00.0007386",
        "data": {
          "message": "Request is being forwarded to the backend service. Timeout set to 300 seconds",
          "request": {
            "method": "GET",
            "url": "https://usa.com/lorem?ipsum=1"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I did not expect it to be so complicated. Also, the screenshots that you have provided are for an actual service that you created. You might want to disable it to prevent it from being accessed.